# Error Django The 'imagem' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

can someone help me understand why the tag:

```
{{ post.author.imagem }}
```

Returns me --> perfil/imagem1.jpg

and the tag

```
{{ post.author.imagem.url }}
```

Returns me an error:
The 'imagem' attribute has no file associated with it.

html

```
{% if post.author.imagem %}
<img src="{{ post.author.imagem.url }}" alt="{{ post.author.first_name }}" 
class="rounded-circle" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; margin-right: 20px;">
{% endif %}
```

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), verbose_name='author', on_delete=models.CASCADE , null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your author/user model?

Comment: Did you add the media views to your `urls.py`?